# React admin custom export button - server side

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I am new to react and react admin.  I have a react admin `List` that is working nicely.  When I enable the `exporter`, it also works as expected.  What I need to do is create a custom exporter that does all the processing on the server.

The main thing I'm unsure about is how I can send the current list of filters and selections to the server to do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this working by adding a button in the `Filter` section that had access to the `filterValues`.

```
const PostFilter = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Filter {...props}>
    </Filter>
    <Button onClick={() => 
      customExport(props.filterValues)}>Export
    </Button>
  </div>
);

export const PostList = (props) => (
    <List {...props} exporter={false} filters={<PostFilter />}>
        ...
    </List>
);

function customExport(filterValues) {
  //javascript goes here to retrieve data from server
}
```